# Which sentence is correct and why (is VS are)

Tags: verb-agreement

"The only thing holding me back is the available colours."

or

"The only thing holding me back are the available colours."

It seems to me like a glitch either way. I slightly favour the second one though.

Comment: I believe the second should be "The only *things* ..." Does that sound better?

Comment: There's only one thing holding you back -- the collective availability of colors.  The verb needs to be singular.

Comment: Why would you favor the second one, please? Any reason why? I am curious.

Comment: Assuming you get subject/verb agreement, the choice is your call.  Using "is" means you're regarding the colors as an indivisible group, while "are" suggests you're considering them individually.

Comment: This is basic grammar, and far too trivial for this site. You might try [ell.se]. It is also a duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/q/17766 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/60888  http://english.stackexchange.com/q/165168 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/23685 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/167271 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/26402

Answer (score 2):

The rule is simple. The verb agrees with the subject of the sentence.

The only thing...is...  [correct]

The only thing...are...  [incorrect]

Comment: Please do not answer duplicates.

Comment: That's a fair comment. If you know of a duplicate it helps if you indicate it.

Comment: It isn't personal: I would say the same to anyone who did this. Please don't answer duplicates, or trivial proofreading questions that show no research. http://english.stackexchange.com/q/17766 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/60888  http://english.stackexchange.com/q/165168 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/23685 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/167271 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/26402

Comment: The personal part was the name-calling. If you are the age you appear to be from your bio, you should have grown out of that by now. I see that has been deleted now.

Answer (score 0):

You can say 'The only thing is' or 'The only things are', but you can not say 'the only thing are'